# ASP.NEt MVC Text to Speech

Tags: text-to-speech

We have a MVC site and now we want to add a functionality where we want to ability to read out text on client side. We display a set of invoices and we want to read out the invoice details. I know you can use System.Speech library with desktop applications to achieve this by pass the details to be read out but does anybody know how can we do this in the MVC project.

Answer (score 2):

Well, this is just off the top of my head and it hasn't been tested but you may be able to do something like this:

```
public ActionResult Speak(string text)
{
    var speech = new SpeechSynthesizer();
    speech.Speak(text);

    byte[] bytes;
    using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        speech.SetOutputToWaveStream(stream);
        bytes = stream.ToArray();
    }
    return File(bytes, "audio/x-wav");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was researching and I found this way, its similar to John Kalberer's answer:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
    {
        Task<FileContentResult> task = Task.Run(() =>
        {
            using (var synth = new SpeechSynthesizer())
            {
                synth.SelectVoice("Microsoft Sabina Desktop");

                using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    synth.SetOutputToWaveStream(stream);
                    synth.Speak("hola mundo");
                    byte[] bytes = stream.GetBuffer();
                    return File(bytes, "audio/x-wav");
                }
            }
        });

        return await task;
    }
```

In this case I'm using the spanish voice, but of course you can select your voice or avoid the `synth.SelectVoice` and use the predeterminated